# Bootstrap X-editable, clear button for textarea

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am wondering if there is any possibility to use the clear button for input type textarea in bootstrap-editable as it is in input type="text" by set of property **clear: true**

Or do I have to use some workaround?

Comment: What plugin are you using? This http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html ?

Comment: Hi Irvin, yes, and X-editable - v1.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any way, I think the reason it's because a textarea is more difficult to style because it's resizable and with more lines.

Without modifying the original code I managed a little hack.

If the `clear` option is true, I use the `shown` event to add a custom button the to the plugin and attach a custom event to clear the textarea content.

Code:

```
$('#dob').on('shown', function (e, editable) {
    if (arguments.length != 2) return
    if (!editable.input.$input.closest('.control-group').find('.editable-input >textarea').length > 0 || !editable.options.clear || editable.input.$input.closest('.control-group:has(".btn-clear")').length > 0) return

    editable.input.$input.closest('.control-group').find('.editable-buttons').append('<br><button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.editable-buttons > .btn-clear', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.control-group').find('.editable-input >textarea').val('');
    return false
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8akfp/

Comment: Your are right, there is no way how to do it better in bootstrap lib. Anyway, your solution seems to me very heavy for my case :) I mean the solution from Dpeif does the same.
But I like the clear button on right, looks good! Thanks

Comment: @stenly you can ask the developer or fork an implementation, but I think this is the only solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually via jQuery like so:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('textarea').val(''); 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peiftronica/r4a5d/)

Comment: That is true, but for the example text type of input allow setup the **clear** property to generate clear button automaticaly.
And I could not find it for **textarea** type of input